# assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast

Tags: c, pointers, casting

```
struct libimg 
{
   Elf32_Phdr ph;
};

struct libimg limg = {
   {
      p_type: PT_LOAD,
      p_memsz: 2 * PAGE_SIZE
   }
};

static void makelib(void *r)
{
    limg.ph.p_vaddr = r;
}
```

And `Elf32_Phdr` is defined in `linux/elf.h`

```
typedef struct elf32_phdr{
   Elf32_Addr    p_vaddr;
   ....
 } Elf32_Phdr;
```

I want to assign `p_vaddr` value from the argument. But I get this warning `assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast`. I use gdb to check and `print r` shows `(void *)0x08040000`

Comment: And your question is....  ?

Comment: @Amit How do I fix this warning? Thanks for your time.

Comment: @HuangJie Which line exactly is producing the error?

Comment: post `Elf32_Phdr` type.

Comment: @PCLuddite Line `limg.ph.p_vaddr = r;` Thanks for your time.

Comment: change the input type from `void *` to whatever type `p_vaddr` is (possibly, an `int`)

Comment: @Amit I don't think the compiler would generate a warning for converting from `void*` to another pointer type without a cast (unless `p_vaddr` isn't a pointer).

Comment: @PCLuddite which is why I wrote *whatever type*, not *whatever pointer type*

Comment: @LPs Thanks for your time. I have posted it.

Comment: @Amit I have posted `Elf32_Phdr` type which is defined in `linux/elf.h`

Comment: `static void makelib(Elf32_Addr r)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is warning you that an assignment caused an implicit cast. It does so because that might have been unintentional, and could potentially have undesirable effects. You could rectify that by using the correct type in the first place:

```
static void makelib(Elf32_Addr r)
{
    limg.ph.p_vaddr = r;
}
```

That might cause other code lines to generate warnings, and you should use a cast in these places, for example:

```
makelib((Elf32_Addr)someVariable);
```

The idea is to cast at the place where you change the meaning of a value from type A to type B, where it's a concise, deliberate decision. You should only do that (casting) if you can't use the proper type in the first place, that is, if `someVariable` can't be `Elf32_Addr`.

Comment: usually we define `p_vaddr` in this way: `p_vaddr: 0x40017000` just like `p_type` and `p_memsz` in the `struct`, but now its value is set to be `1073836032`. Can we say they are the same?

Comment: @HuangJie Open your calculator and put hexadecimal value and convert it to decimal. You'll find that are the same value.

Comment: @LPs Thanks for your reply. Yes, I see it.

Answer (score 0):

In [Linux/arch/powerpc/boot/elf.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/powerpc/boot/elf.h#L103)

```
 94 typedef struct elf32_phdr {
 95         Elf32_Word p_type;
 96         Elf32_Off p_offset;
 97         Elf32_Addr p_vaddr;
 98         Elf32_Addr p_paddr;
 99         Elf32_Word p_filesz;
100         Elf32_Word p_memsz;
101         Elf32_Word p_flags;
102         Elf32_Word p_align;
103 } Elf32_Phdr;
```

Where `Elf32_Addr`

```
typedef unsigned int Elf32_Addr;
```

Finally you are assigning a `void *` to a `unsigned int`

Cast it as `unsigned int` or better to `Elf32_Addr` to avoid warning:

```
limg.ph.p_vaddr = (Elf32_Addr)r;
```

Comment: No, either cast it to `Elf32_Addr`, or accept that as an input in the first place.

Comment: @Amit My solution works, probably not the coolest or the more standard one.

Comment: @LPs - I didn't say it doesn't work. HuangJie asked a question, I thought my answer relevant and appropriate. (It's not about being cool :-)